# NHibernate - after Refresh Session is still dirty

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've run into a problem with NH (v2.1.2) still thinking the session is dirty after I've refreshed the only entity that was modified in that session.

I have a parent->child relation set up with this mapping like this:

```
<set name="ChildItem" access="field.camelcase-underscore"
     lazy="true"
     cascade="save-update"
     inverse="true">
  <key column="PARENT_ITEM_KEY"/>
  <one-to-many class="....ChildItem"/>
</set>
```

Here's the steps to reproduce the problem:

1 - Create new ChildItem and add it to the Parent's collection, but don't save it. Now session.IsDirty() returns true (as expected).

2 - Call session.Refresh(parent) to revert my change.  After the refresh, the parent's collection now does not contain the new child item (as expected).

3 - Now session.IsDirty() returns **true** - although I'd expect false, as I've refreshed the only item that was modified.

Digging into the SessionImpl via the debugger, I can see that NH still has a pending Insert for the new ChildItem in it's ActionQueue.

Is it possible to return the session to an IsDirty()=false state in this scenario? I don't want to have to discard the whole session for this.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there doesn't seem to be an answer for this one.
In the end it seems dropping the working session was the only way to discard the change.  It meant a day or so of refactoring/retesting but it's up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following instead of `Refresh()`. This is the usual workaround for problems with `Refresh()`, but I don't know if it will help in your case.

```
session.Evict(parent);
session.Load(parent, parent.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't help me.  Regardless of whether I refresh or evict the parent entity the NH session still returns IsDirty() = true .. i.e. it still thinks it's got a pending insert for that transient child.